# i have some problems in java Class i cant get EditText as string

Tags: java, android, string, class, onclicklistener

> package com.example.dato.task;
>
> import android.app.DialogFragment; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.support.annotation.Nullable; import
>   android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import
>   android.view.ViewGroup; import android.view.Window; import
>   android.widget.Button; import android.widget.EditText; /**  * Created
>   by DATO on 2/17/2018.  */
>
> public class DialogClass extends DialogFragment{
>
> ```
> public DialogClass(){}
>
> String s;
> String s1;
>
> @Nullable
> @Override
> public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     final View dialogView= View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog, null);
>
>     getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>
>       final EditText e1 = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
>       final EditText e2= dialogView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
>          Button bt = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
>
>
>
>     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view){
>         s = e1.getText().toString();
>         s1 = e2.getText().toString();
>         dismiss();
>         }
>     });
>
>     return dialogView;
> }
> ```

```
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.dato.task, PID: 1898
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.dato.task.DialogClass$1.onClick(DialogClass.java:47)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Comment: this kind it cant understand  s = e1.getText().toString(); and s1 = e2.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably that in your `dialog.xml` layout you haven't the editTexts with the IDs "text1" and "text2".

The IDs can be different.